# Debug Terraform, Missing Argument Domain

Tags: terraform

Terraform logs when running `TF_LOG=debug terraform plan`

```
Providers required by configuration:
Waiting for the plan to start...

Terraform v1.4.6
on linux_amd64
Initializing plugins and modules...
data.ec_stack.latest: Refreshing...
data.ec_stack.latest: Refresh complete after 0s [id=8.7.1]
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│ The argument "domain" is required, but was not set.
╵
Operation failed: failed running terraform plan (exit 1)
```

Getting a really vague error and have no idea what is causing it with debug logs enabled. Anyone have any ideas to make it easier to debug this type of error?

Comment: Is this not also failing during `validate`?

Comment: `Success! The configuration is valid.` When I run validate @MattSchuchard

Comment: This seems like what some older versions of Terraform would do if you omitted a `provider` block for a provider with a required argument. Since there is no `provider` block to refer to, the diagnostic renderer would not know what to associated the message with. However, you are using a version of Terraform that is new enough that I would expect it to fail in that case by telling you that the provider block is required, so perhaps something different is happening here.

Comment: Just in case though: are you using any providers in this configuration whose `provider` blocks might require an argument called `domain`?

Comment: I didn’t think about the providers, so I just checked there and I’m using Auth0 provider which has the domain argument specified. I have the Auth0 provider specified twice with alias for prod and staging, I wonder if that is messing with things

Comment: Banging head off a wall, think I'm going to have to figure it out by process of elimination by removing terraform component one by one. Just going to take a while, thought there might've been a easier way to get a trace callback or something

Comment: Finally pinpointed it, refactored all the terraform too in process. Was Auth0 auth0_custom_domain I think due to the account not having a custom domain included in the subscription.

Comment: I know exactly why I used Auth0 provider twice with two diff alias, but I didn't explicitly state which provider to use when calling auth0_custom_domain